# Regex doesnt match the groups (Python)

Tags: python, regex, list

On my administration page I have a list of accounts with various values that I wanna to capture, like id, name, type, etc. On Regex101 its capturing perfectly all the values with "g" and "s" modifiers active.
This what I trying to do:

```
def extract_accounts(src):
        list_accounts = []
        try:
            pattern = re.compile(r'''id=(?P<id>.*?)&serverzone=.\">(?P<name>[a-zA-Z].*?)<\/a>.*?75px;\">(?P<level>.*?)<\/td>.*?75px;.*?75px;\">(?P<type>.*?)<\/td>.*?Open!''', re.X)
            print type(pattern)
            match = pattern.match(src)
            print match, "type=", type(match)
            name = match.group("name")
            print "name", name
            ids = match.group("id")
            level = match.group("level")
            type = match.group("type")
            #list_accounts.append(name, ids, level, type)
            #print ("id=", ids, ", name=",name," level=", level, " type=", type)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

But somehow I get this:

```
<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
None type= <type 'NoneType'>
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong. 
Basically what I want is to put in a list = [(name1, id1, level1, type), (name2, id2, level1, type) ..... and so on the things that I grab from each line
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you print some sample string to test

Comment: Sure, this is the link > https://regex101.com/r/vQ8jB0/1

Comment: i cant find an error in the regex, however i get an error when running `re.findall()` because of a special character in the string, in your case its the • next to Evolution. python can't handle that

Comment: @LawrenceBenson to decode the string into "windows-1252" which supports that char and py can handle it?

Comment: @MikeThunder - I have updated my answer. Let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: if you replace  "print(e)" with "raise e" you will get also get a traceback of the error, which might help finding the problem.

Comment: @jelle doesn't matter, because the answer will be the same: Process finished with exit code 0. Which means that he doesn't find nothing in string. If I will cut the last 2, the script works perfectly, they are the ones after those creepy chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be capturing groups by their group number. I have changed the regular expression completely and implemented it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import re

def main():
    sample_data = '''
    <tr style="background-color: #343222;">
        <td style="width: 20px;"><img src="/images/Star.png" style="border: 0px;" /></td>
        <td><a target="_top" href="adminzone.php?id=2478&serverid=1">Mike</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">74</td>
        <td>•Evolu†ion•</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 100px;">1635</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">40,826</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">User</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><a target="_top" href="href="adminzone.php"><strong>Open!</strong></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #3423323;">
        <td style="width: 20px;"><img src="/images/Star.png" style="border: 0px;" /></td>
        <td><a target="_top" href="adminzone.php?suid=24800565&serverid=1">John</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">70</td>
        <td>•Evolu†ion•</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 100px;">9167</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">36,223</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 75px;">Admin</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;"><a style="color: #00DD19;" target="_top" href="adminzone.php?id=248005&serverid=1"><strong>Open!</strong></a></td>

'''

    matchObj = re.search('id=(.*)&serverid=.">(.*)<\\/a><\\/td>\\n.*?75px;\\">(.+)<\\/td>\\n.*\\n.*\\n.*75px;\\">(.+)<\\/td>\\n.*75px;\\">(.+)<\\/td>', sample_data, re.X)

    if matchObj:
        user_id = matchObj.group(1)
        name = matchObj.group(2)
        level = matchObj.group(3)
        user_type = matchObj.group(4)
        print user_id, name, level, user_type


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:
`2478 Mike 74 40,826`

The above should give you a basic idea. Just incase you might be wondering, `group(0)` is the entire regular expression.

Comment: @MikeThunder has this solved your issue or not? If you have any further difficulties let me know so that I may assist further.

Comment: I found the problem . Forgot to add re.S for multiple lines :(